# comparing a line with its following lines

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk, while-loop

I have a file named `file.txt` which contains data in the following format:

```
John
file
Abr
John
Tutu
```

I can read the file line by line using the following way:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read fl
do
echo $fl
done < file.txt
```

But I want to print a line with its following lines

I tried the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
prev=""
while read fl; do
    prev="$fl"
done < file.txt
```

But this script does the things with consecutive lines only. please suggest some better solution.

Expected output:

```
John  file
John Abr
John John
John Tutu

then
file  Abr
file John
file Tutu

then
Abr John
Abr Tutu

then
John Tutu
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please also share expected output in your question to make it more clear.

Comment: The script you tried has no echo statements and will not output anything.

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With single pass Input_file please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
{
  arr[FNR]=$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    for(j=(i+1);j<=FNR;j++){
      print arr[i],arr[j]
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  arr[FNR]=$0                    ##Creating arr with index of FNR and value of $0.
}
END{                             ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){           ##Running 1st loop till FNR value.
    for(j=(i+1);j<=FNR;j++){     ##Running 2nd loop till FNR value, with starting value i+1 here.
      print arr[i],arr[j]        ##Printing array with index of i and j here.
    }
  }
}
' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[++count]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i=(FNR+1);i<=count;i++){
    print $0,arr[i]
  }
}
' Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition FNR==NR here.
  arr[++count]=$0                 ##Creating array with index of count with increasing value of 1 and its value is current line.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=(FNR+1);i<=count;i++){    ##Running loop from next line to count here.
    print $0,arr[i]               ##Printing current line and array element here.
  }
}
' Input_file  Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh for ur answer....it solved the problem

Comment: @anonymossi, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

awk's empty RS might suit your data:

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS= '{for (i=1;i<NF;++i) for (j=i+1;j<=NF;++j) print $i,$j}' file
```

Comment: Your answer would be even better if  you explained your code.

Comment: @Nic3500 no it wouldn't because this is utterly trivial, basic, common awk code and anyone who doesn't understand it will quickly figure it out from a quick google and/or glance at the man page and by doing so will learn far more than if this code was explained step by step and they just read that. It's not reasonable or useful to comment basic, trivial code in every answer posted. rowboat did exactly the right thing by posting it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive bash function

```sh
#!/bin/bash

list_compare() {
    test ${#@} -lt 2 && return  # terminating condition

    local name="$1"
    shift
    for e in "${@}"; do
        echo -n "$name $e"
        test "$name" == "$e" && echo ' <- match' || echo
    done
    echo
    list_compare "$@"  # call again with what's left after shift
}

list_compare $(<file.txt)
```

Output

```
John file
John Abr
John John <- match
John Tutu

file Abr
file John
file Tutu

Abr John
Abr Tutu

John Tutu
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output order doesn't matter then:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR > 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NR; i++) {
        print words[i], $0
    }
}
{ words[NR]=$0 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
John    file
John    Abr
file    Abr
John    John
file    John
Abr     John
John    Tutu
file    Tutu
Abr     Tutu
John    Tutu
```

or if it does:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR > 1 {
    for (i=1; i<NR; i++) {
        print i, NR, words[i], $0
    }
}
{ words[NR]=$0 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1,2n | cut -f3-
John    file
John    Abr
John    John
John    Tutu
file    Abr
file    John
file    Tutu
Abr     John
Abr     Tutu
John    Tutu
```